# Python pyModis installation give error on windows 10 using pip install pyModis

Tags: python, gdal, pymodis

I am using windows 10 operating system on my HP i7 machine with Python 2.7 installed. For windows, it is possible to install pyModis using pip by writing the following syntax in Windows PowerShell:

```
pip install pyModis
```

But it give me error like:

> ```
>   Failed building wheel for GDAL Failed to build GDAL Installing collected packages: GDAL   Running setup.py install for GDAL
> Complete output from command c:\python2.7\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\oaamer\\ap
> ```
>
> pdata\local\temp\pip-build-j1djwe\GDAL\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().repl ace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   c:\users\oaamer\appdata\local\temp\pip-njzqtm-record\install-rec
>   ord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       running build_ext
>       building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
>       C:\Users\oaamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD / W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG
>   -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -Ic:\python2.7\include -Ic:\python2.7\PC -Ic:\pytho n2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-win32.egg\numpy\core\include
>   /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.
>   7\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj
>       gdal_wrap.cpp
>       C:\Users\oaamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception
>   handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>       extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(2859) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or director y
>       error: command 'C:\Users\oaamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\ \cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

how to fix that error i have tried so many times to fix read different blogs but did not find the possible solution as windows does not provide friendly environment.

Comment: The problem here is GDAL and not  pyModis. On Windows, you cannot install  GDAL with pip (no native compiler). Try to install GDAL first then pyModis

Comment: @gene thanks. would you please guide me how to install GDAL on windows 10. What if i have installed QGIS which has already built in GDAL installation then.

Comment: What Python version you are using,  the one from QGIS or another ?

Comment: @gene I have just recently installed the Python 3.5. Old version was Python 2.7. Python 3.5 is newly installed separately on windows 10. I have also installed QGIS 2.6.

Comment: You cannot use the GDAL version of QGIS (for Python 2.7.x) with Python 3.5 . Try to install it (for Python 3.5) from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)